# Must one give his father the head of the table?

Tags: kibbud-av-veim-honoring

If your father is a guest in your home for a meal (ex. Sabbath) are you under duty to give him the head of the table due to the commandment of honoring your father?

Comment: Note if the father would feel weird or prefers (shepping nachas) the son sitting up front (as is almost always the case) there is certainly no obligation. This question is largely theoretical.

Answer (score 4):

The Aruch Hashulchan in Yoreh Deah siman 240 siff 11 seen [here](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%9E#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.A8.D7.9E_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.99.D7.90) says no. The son keeps his seat at the head. His reasoning was that since it's the son's house and his wife sits next to him, it would be improper for the father to sit at the head next to his daughter in law. (However that works out.)

He goes on to say that all other honors should go to the father first, such as washing and receiving the first portion of food.

Comment: That does seem to be what he says but I don't see how it makes any sense. Just move the daughter in law next to the son, and the mother next to the father. What's the problem?

Comment: That's why I stuck in the parenthetical however that works out. She also has to honor her father in law siff 24. It also might contradict the A.H. himself in siff 9 where he says that women don't generally have a makom kavua.

Comment: @user6591 - Anyway I'm not sure the Aruch Hashulchan's would-be problem is even applicable to the case of the questioner - the Aruch Hashulchan is talking about when the parent is elderly and moves in with his kids - it's a permanent arrangement, he lives there now, so there is more reason for him to sit at the head. The questioner is asking about a casual visit.

Comment: @Jay you are entitled to that opinion. I would assume that in those times having your father travel to you for a shabbos was not too common. He was just setting up a common situation as he ends off with pointing out that is the minhag.

Comment: @Jay I'm also not sure what you mean by more of a "reason for him". Who's "him"?

Comment: @user6591 - by 'him' I meant the parent. I'm not sure why you would assume parents didn't visit their children (or that there was usually 'traveling' involved). I would assume the opposite!

Comment: @Jay if him means the father and there is more reason for him to sit at the head and he doesn't there would be a kal vichomer to the case you think is different and he certainly would not sit at the head. I would say it's a hu hadin.

Comment: @user6591 - I'm not sure what you meant with that, but regardless I want you to know that I'm not saying definitively that you're wrong, I'm just pointing out the possibility that there MAY BE a difference between a casual visit and moving in, based on the case he uses. I guess in the back of my mind is that the S.A. when discussing not sitting in his father's seat ('bveiso'), gives the impression that it's only because it's his father's designated seat that there's a problem sitting there.

Comment: @user6591 - ...The A.H. (9) introduces the concept that the head of the table is where the 'baal habayis' sits, and therefore the child can't sit there. So I'm thinking maybe when a parent moves in, he should become the 'baal habayis' so to speak. Whereas when he's just visiting, he's not part of the household, so it's a not lack of respect for him to sit in the guest's place.

Comment: @Jay again A.H. says when father moves in he does NOT sit at the head.

Comment: @user6591 -  he does not sit at the head because of the daughter-in-law issue (or mechilah). But the implication is, IF NOT FOR THAT, there would indeed be a problem with the son sitting at the head. I am suggesting that were this to be a casual visit, the A.H. wouldn't have to come on to those reasons - there is simply no kibud av issue in such a case.

Answer (score 2):

Although, as [noted](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/75451/13811) earlier, the [Aruch Hashulchan YD (240:11)](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.240.11?lang=bi) writes the son sits at the head, the sefer Moreh Horim UKevodom (1:52) quotes Rav Elyashiv and Rav Benzion Abba Shaul who both say the son should have his father sit at the head of the table.

Additionally, the [Sefer Habayis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1583304444) (26:23) writes:

> When one hosts parents at his house, he must honor them, have them
> wash their hands, and serve them food, before other members of the
> household. It is proper to seat his father at the head of the table.